# Search on developer.android.com from Firefox search bar?

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon

Is there available search addon for the same? (hopefully, with autocomplete functionality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for `developer.android.com` on [**Mycroft returns one result**](http://mycroft.mozdev.org/search-engines.html?name=developer.android.com) that might be interesting.

No auto-complete, though :-(